Is there a way to detect at compile time that I’m not filling needed fields of these structs?
I'm using structs like the below in my Rust app:
pub struct Invoice {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub amount: i64,
    pub rows: Vec<InvoiceRow>,
    pub company: Option<Box<Company>>,
    pub customer: Option<Box<Customer>>,
    pub payments: Vec<Payment>,
    // and many many others
}

pub struct Payment {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub amount: i64,
    pub invoice_id: Uuid,
    pub payment_method_id: Uuid,
    pub payment_method: Option<Box<PaymentMethod>>,
    // and many many others
}

pub struct PaymentMethod {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub name: String,
    pub mode: String,
    // and many many others
}

Than I have methods like this:
fn payments(invoice: &Invoice) -> String {
    let payments = invoice
        .payments
        .iter()
        .fold(String::new(), |mut output, payment| {
            let _ = write!(
                output,
                "mode: {mode} - amount: {amount}\n",
                mode = payment.payment_method.as_ref().expect("payment_method").mode(),
                amount = payment.amount(),
            );
            output
        });

    payments
}

In this case Invoice is being created from a DB call which can query payments field (Vec<Payment>) based on a code like this:
pub struct InvoiceFieldsToQuery {
    pub rows: Option<Box<InvoiceRowFieldsToQuery>>,
    pub company: Option<Box<CompanyFieldsToQuery>>,
    pub customer: Option<Box<CustomerFieldsToQuery>>,
    pub payments: Option<Box<PaymentFieldsToQuery>>,
    // and many many others
}

let fields_to_query = InvoiceFieldsToQuery::default()
    .query_company(Some(Box::new(
        CompanyFieldsToQuery::default().query_address(),
    )))
    .query_customer(Some(Box::new(
        CustomerFieldsToQuery::default().query_address(),
    )))
    .query_payments(Some(Box::new(
        PaymentFieldsToQuery::default())
    ));
    // and many many others

As you can see I'm using code like .expect("payment_method") that I don't want to use.
Is there a way to avoid the usage of .expect() using something to detect and block at compile time a struct without a field?
Or - better - a way to detect at compile time that I'll need to use payments (or rows etc.) and its payment_method so I must query it with .query_payments(Some(Box::new(PaymentFieldsToQuery::default())))?
I need those fields to be Option because I'm querying them only when I need them. And I don't always need them.
For example for Invoice sometimes I need rows, payments and customer, sometimes just customer.
This is the issue.
I would like to detect at compile time when I need payments that I'm passing an Invoice struct with payments field filled.
I'm ready to change everything in my code to achieve this compile time check!

Are you always filling all of your fields?

Also? How far are you ready to go? For example, will you agree to make the struct generic for that?

I'm filling the fields only when I know I'll use them in a subsequent method. But sometimes I forget to fill those fields hence this answer. I'm ready to change everything.

Easiest way is to make 2 versions of every struct. One where every field is optional and one where they are all required. Then add a method to convert one to another but only if all the fields are filled. A macro could do this for you automatically.

I agree with @mousetail I think the most idiomatic approach is to create a new struct InvoiceWithPayments that has payments as non-optional and implements TryFrom Invoice. Then functions that rely on the payments field can use InvoiceWithPayments parameters instead, and the caller can convert between and handle failures.

@AdamSmith but Invoice has many fields, not only payments.

@FredHors ah I missed that you need the same solution for the other fields. Still, since you're loading these invoices from a database you must do runtime evaluation at some point. The question is only where you want to write your guards.

Yeah. But this is all the issue.

@AdamSmith can you write a small example? I don't understand.

@FredHors since your data cannot be known at compile time, something has to check for invalid data to be type safe. In your example you chose that the consumer function makes that check (fn payments checks to make sure that the invoice has a valid payment). I don't think there's anything wrong with that. However if you wanted type safety, you could instead move that logic to a Invoice::new function or, indeed, the query function itself. I expect there are a small number of data configurations for a valid invoice (and not that any given field might be null in the DB) [1/2]

@FredHors and so I would write structs that match each valid configuration and create TryFrom implementations that let the calling code (whatever is calling fn payments) move from one to another. [2/2]

@AdamSmith thanks! Can you write an example?

Here's a nice idea, that I honestly don't know if it is worth it. But it's your choice :)
The idea is to replace the Option with a type-level Option. That is, differentiate between Some and None via different types. We provide a trait to handle them dynamically as runtime Options, and when you need one state specifically you can require it via the type.
The trait:
pub struct Missing;
pub struct Existing;

pub trait MaybeMissing {
    type Repr<T: ?Sized>: MaybeMissingRepr<T>;
    fn map<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized>(
        v: Self::Repr<T>,
        f: impl FnOnce(Box<T>) -> Box<U>,
    ) -> Self::Repr<U>;
}

impl MaybeMissing for Existing {
    type Repr<T: ?Sized> = Box<T>;
    fn map<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized>(
        v: Self::Repr<T>,
        f: impl FnOnce(Box<T>) -> Box<U>,
    ) -> Self::Repr<U> {
        f(v)
    }
}

impl MaybeMissing for Missing {
    type Repr<T: ?Sized> = Missing;
    fn map<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized>(
        _v: Self::Repr<T>,
        _f: impl FnOnce(Box<T>) -> Box<U>,
    ) -> Self::Repr<U> {
        Missing
    }
}

pub trait MaybeMissingRepr<T: ?Sized> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T>;
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T>;
    fn into_owned(self) -> Option<Box<T>>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized> MaybeMissingRepr<T> for Box<T> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        Some(&**self)
    }
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T> {
        Some(&mut **self)
    }
    fn into_owned(self) -> Option<Box<T>> {
        Some(self)
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> MaybeMissingRepr<T> for Missing {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        None
    }
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T> {
        None
    }
    fn into_owned(self) -> Option<Box<T>> {
        None
    }
}

The structs:
pub struct Invoice<
    CompanyOpt: MaybeMissing,
    CustomerOpt: MaybeMissing,
    PaymentMethodOpt: MaybeMissing,
> {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub amount: i64,
    pub rows: Vec<InvoiceRow>,
    pub company: CompanyOpt::Repr<Company>,
    pub customer: CustomerOpt::Repr<Customer>,
    pub payments: Vec<Payment<PaymentMethodOpt>>,
    // and many many others
}

pub struct Payment<PaymentMethodOpt: MaybeMissing> {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub amount: i64,
    pub invoice_id: Uuid,
    pub payment_method_id: Uuid,
    pub payment_method: PaymentMethodOpt::Repr<PaymentMethod>,
    // and many many others
}

pub struct PaymentMethod {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub name: String,
    pub mode: String,
    // and many many others
}

The DB query methods:
pub struct InvoiceFieldsToQuery<
    RowsOpt: MaybeMissing,
    CompanyOpt: MaybeMissing,
    CustomerOpt: MaybeMissing,
    PaymentsOpt: MaybeMissing,
> {
    pub rows: RowsOpt::Repr<InvoiceRowFieldsToQuery>,
    pub company: CompanyOpt::Repr<CompanyFieldsToQuery>,
    pub customer: CustomerOpt::Repr<CustomerFieldsToQuery>,
    pub payments: PaymentsOpt::Repr<PaymentFieldsToQuery>,
    // and many many others
}

impl Default for InvoiceFieldsToQuery<Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            rows: Missing,
            company: Missing,
            customer: Missing,
            payments: Missing,
            // and many many others
        }
    }
}

impl<CompanyOpt: MaybeMissing, CustomerOpt: MaybeMissing, PaymentsOpt: MaybeMissing>
    InvoiceFieldsToQuery<Missing, CompanyOpt, CustomerOpt, PaymentsOpt>
{
    pub fn query_rows(
        self, /* ... */
    ) -> InvoiceFieldsToQuery<Existing, CompanyOpt, CustomerOpt, PaymentsOpt> {
        InvoiceFieldsToQuery {
            rows: Box::new(/* query rows */),
            company: self.company,
            customer: self.customer,
            payments: self.payments,
            // and many many others
        }
    }
}

// Etc., more `query_` methods.

impl<
        RowsOpt: MaybeMissing,
        CompanyOpt: MaybeMissing,
        CustomerOpt: MaybeMissing,
        PaymentsOpt: MaybeMissing,
    > InvoiceFieldsToQuery<RowsOpt, CompanyOpt, CustomerOpt, PaymentsOpt>
{
    pub fn query(self) -> Invoice<CompanyOpt, CustomerOpt, PaymentsOpt> {
        Invoice {
            company: CompanyOpt::map(self.company, |company| /* query DB */),
            // And more...
        }
    }
}

And finally, the methods requiring a value:
fn payments<CompanyOpt: MaybeMissing, CustomerOpt: MaybeMissing>(invoice: &Invoice<CompanyOpt, CustomerOpt, Existing>) -> String {
    let payments = invoice
        .payments
        .iter()
        .fold(String::new(), |mut output, payment| {
            let _ = write!(
                output,
                "mode: {mode} - amount: {amount}\n",
                // No `expect()`!
                mode = payment.payment_method.mode(),
                amount = payment.amount(),
            );
            output
        });

    payments
}


This is neat, but I'm not sure it's good, you know? Type magic is awesome, but the generics seem like they'd make changes to this code base an absolute pain. I think this is probably hiding some business rule-level assertions we can make about the data.

@ChayimFriedman I'm trying to understand your code. But how to use it? Should I declare a new Invoice like: let invoice: Invoice<CompanyOpt, CustomerOpt, Existing> = Invoice {}???

@FredHors The idea is not you never construct Invoice with opaque generic parameters. Only with concrete types. So you will have the end code that will construct Invoice (or any kind of builder) and define what it wants it to include, and other code will only make transformation on this type.

@ChayimFriedman can you write an example of usage? I cannot understand.

@AdamSmith I myself said that I don't know if the idea is worth it. So I definitely won't deny the concern. But I don't see any other way to do that (assuming arbitrary sets of activated subfields). So OP will have to chose what they prefers, the advantages of not having generics or the better chance of catching errors with missing fields.

I wrote an (almost full) example of usage, I titled as "the DB query methods". This is only an example; your real code will probably be different and may even require different methods on the traits for the transformations. But I gave you the rough idea, and I hope you can adjust it to whatever exactly you need.

@ChayimFriedman thanks. I'm asking an usage example to understand how to use your magical code. For example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1518cfa7ef4a61f0df3c836fcd0c2a96. Why all these errors? I used let invoice: Invoice<Existing, Existing, MaybeMissing> = Invoice {. Is this the correct way to use it?

@FredHors A value might be either Existing with value Box<T> or Missing with value Missing. MaybeMissing is not an option, as is mixing missing and existing in an array. If you need that, also have a third type MaybeMissingType implementing MaybeMissing with Repr<T> = Option<Box<T>>.

@ChayimFriedman I think I found a way to use it like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=86c739861a84d4580c1cf9b2d8f195aa. What do you think? let invoice: Invoice<Existing, Missing, Existing> = Invoice {}

@FredHors Indeed, your later example is how it's supposed to be used.

Your code is amazing! Thanks!
